# Infinity loop with useEffect and OnChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an error with a useEffect hook and an a custom Input component. (React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.)

The input value can be change by the user and also automatically by a useEffect.

When the value of my component changes automatically, the input takes the correct value but when I write something manually in the input, the error occurs

Have you got any idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Pedro.

This is my component in my app

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (someValue === 0) {
        setSequestrationForm((previousValues) => ({
            ...previousValues,
            percent: value
    }))
}, [someValue])


  <CoverageInput
      onChange={(value?: number) => {
         setPercentForm((previousValues) => ({
             ...previousValues,
             percent: value
         }))
      }}
      name="percent"
      value={percent}
      label="percent"
  />
```

This is the external component

```
const CoverageInput = ({
   onChange,
   onFocus,
   onBlur,
   value
}: Props) => {

const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState<string>(value)

useEffect(() => {
    setInternalValue(value) 
}, [value])

return (
    <CustomInput
        {...props}
        value={internalValue}
    />
```

Comment: How component `CustomInput` look like?

Comment: Is `CoverageInput` supposed to be a controlled or uncontrolled input? Seems you are duplicating state, an anti-pattern in React. What is the intended source of truth for this input and parent component?

Answer (score 0):

ok its happened to me also ... but its simple.

your problem is using dependence in the use effect

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setInternalValue(value) 
    }, [value])
```

and update the state in useEffect to
so useEffect returns a function when the dependence changes and you changing the dependence in the useEffect

delete dependence to fix